# How many ways can 4 different balls can be arranged in 3 different boxes if each box can have 1 or more balls.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I can solve for $4$ different balls arranged in $3$ boxes if a box can contain $0$ or more :
$$3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3$$

But what if a box can contain $1$ or more.

If balls were indistinguishable we can use combinatorics to solve, but in this case, balls are distinguished.

Would it be : $3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 3$ ?

Comment: Pick the box that contains $2$.  Assign the balls accordingly.

Comment: choose $2$ balls out of $4$ and any of the three boxes can have $2$ balls. Then you are left with $2$ balls to place in rest two boxes.

Comment: It works given the numbers are small otherwise you will have to look at a more generic approach, like Principle of Inclusion Exclusion, Stirling Number of the second kind etc.

Comment: @MathLover you mean 4C2 * 3! * 2! * 2C2 * 2!   ?

Comment: Can you please explain what is what? I get the first which is ${4 \choose 2}$.